# How to adapt the text to the container dimension?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I made a responsive layout that [you can see here](https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/16123/). This is the code:

```
<div class="frame-content">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="command-buttons tile col-xs-6 btn">
      <h3 class="title">Appuntamenti futuri</h3>
      <p>Hello Blue, this is a colored tile.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="command-buttons tile col-xs-6 btn">
      <h3 class="title">Storico</h3>
      <p>Hello Blue, this is a colored tile.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="command-buttons tile col-xs-12 btn">
      <h3 class="title">Prenota</h3>
      <p>Hello Blue, this is a colored tile.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="command-buttons tile col-xs-6 btn">
      <h3 class="title">Card</h3>
      <p>Hello Blue, this is a colored tile.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="command-buttons tile col-xs-6 btn">
      <h3 class="title">Abbonamento prepagate</h3>
      <p>Hello Blue, this is a colored tile.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Now the problem is that if I reduce the window dimension (and of course on mobile smartphone) the text overlap the other container. How I can prevent this situation?

Comment: You may add `overflow: hidden;` to the `btn` class, while removeing the `white-space: nowrap;` from `btn` class

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem stems from a property that Bootstrap's `btn` class adds: `white-space: no-wrap`. This prevents the text from wrapping to a new line. You can override this with a simple CSS property: `white-space: normal`

However, longer words can still overflow since, by default, breaks only happen between words and not between characters. To fix this, you can add one of two additional properties, either `word-wrap: break-word` or `word-break: break-all`.

`word-wrap` generally looks nicer in most layouts as it attempts to avoid breaking a word unless it needs to.
`word-break` will just break as soon as it needs to but it has wider browser support.

Example, using word-wrap:

```
.command-buttons {
  white-space: normal;
  word-wrap: break-word;
}
```

Useful links:
[`word-wrap` browser support breakdown](http://caniuse.com/#feat=wordwrap)
[`word-break` browser support breakdown](http://caniuse.com/#feat=word-break)

Your [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/6Lxd1uh1/) updated using `word-wrap`.
Your [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rkjp2qhL/) updated using `word-break`.

Comment: I've updated the jfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/16125/ I don't know if I did something wrong with your solution, but if I reduce the window dimension I still get the text overlap in the other div

Comment: I believe what you are referring to is that some of the longer words are still overlapping. If that is the case, you can also add an additional property `word-break: break-all`. This will make it so that breaks can happen between letters. This change to the behavior of breaks can be somewhat unpleasant in some layouts so you'll have to decide if it is acceptable.

Comment: you're right, now seems working well. Thanks for this, have a good day :)

Comment: I've looked into it a little further and remembered the `word-wrap` property which generally looks nicer in layouts (as long as the browsers you are targeting support it)

Comment: I didn't put the downvote to you, if anything, I put upvote for a good answer.